# angular release timing general strategy?

Tags: angular

Does Angular have a general strategy for release timing? For example, the following url appears to list a full release history for ng5, from beta.0 to current state:

https://jaxenter.com/road-to-angular-5-133253.html

The schedule starts from 05/01/2017 with the ng2 major version release scheduled for 09/18/2017. Following the pattern of this schedule, it looks like Angular may plan to release a new version at least twice/year. Does anyone here know if this pattern aligns with the current intentions of Angular team going forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find their plans here: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/10/versioning-and-releasing-angular.html

The good news is that since they are updating frequently, the changes from release to release are now minor ... making it very easy to upgrade from one version to the next.

There is also a tool to help you migrate from one version to the next by identifying the changes that may affect you. You can find that here: http://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com